# Javascript function to show/hide URLs in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have about 30 URLS for server1 and 30 for server2. I want a java script generic function to hide and show URL based on the checkbox selection.

For example:
checkbox1 URL1(default hidden) URL2(default visible) [if check box is selected then only show URL1 and Hide URL2 and vice versa ]

checkbox2 URL3(default hidden) URL4(default visible) [if check box is selected then only show URL3 and Hide URL4 and vice versa]

checkbox3 URL5(default hidden) URL5(default visible) [if check box is selected then only show URL5 and Hide URL6 and vice versa]

I can have any of the checkbox selected and unselected. Each checkbox should handle only a particular pair mentioned against it.

I have written a function but it works only for one pair of URLs. I don't know how to make sure that a give checkbox works with a particular set of URLs against it.

```js
function toggle_urls(checkbox) {
  var id2 = checkbox.id;
  var search_pattern2 = /checkbox(.*?)$/g;
  var number2 = search_pattern2.exec(id2);
  number2 = number2[1];
  box_id2 = 'box' + number2;
  var box2 = document.getElementById(box_id2);
  if (checkbox.checked) {
    box2.style.display = 'inline';
  } else {
    box2.style.display = 'none';
  }
  var id3 = checkbox.name;
  var search_pattern3 = /checkbox(.*?)$/g;
  var number3 = search_pattern3.exec(id3);
  number3 = number3[1];
  box_id3 = 'box' + number3;
  var box3 = document.getElementById(box_id3);
  if (checkbox.checked) {
    box3.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    box3.style.display = 'inline';
  }
}
```

```html
<li>
  <label>Toggle</label>
  <input onChange="toggle_urls(this)" id="checkbox2" name=checkbox3 type="checkbox">
  <a id="box2" style="display:none;" href="URL1">Server1 URL1</a>
  <a id="box3" style="display:inline;" href="URL2">Server2 URL2</a>
</li>
<li>
  <label>Toggle2</label>
  <input onChange="toggle_urls(this)" id="checkbox2" name=checkbox3 type="checkbox">
  <a id="box2" style="display:none;" href="URL3">Server1 URL3</a>
  <a id="box3" style="display:inline;" href="URL4">Server2 URL4</a>
</li>
```

I want a particular checkbox to show/hide a pair of URLs. There will be 15 check boxes and 15 URLs set against them.

Comment: Please post what you have so far. Html/javascript preferably in a snippet.

Comment: Welcome. Please see [How to make an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @MarkBaijens I tried to add my code but this site is asking to indent it which I tried but it's not accepting it.

Comment: If you're having formatting trouble just do your best and someone else will fix it.

Comment: When you edit your question click the document icon with `<>` in it. There you can create a snippet. There is also a code formatting functionality in that snippet.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. I have formatted at some extent and managed to post the code.

Comment: you are using duplicated id's. Id's need to be unique.

Comment: @MarkBaijens that's right but the JS calculate the id based on html object which is checkbox. I don't know how to make sure that only a particular set of ids are picked based on the particular checkbox object. I want toggle2 to work same as toggle but on the set of URLs mentioned against it. Clearly, my code only works for toggle and even toggle 2 act on first set of URLs because Ids are same.

Answer (score 0):

You may be overworking your solution...

<s>You have a series of choices, where only one option can be active at a time.  Instead of a checkbox, you can use radio buttons.</s>

Instead of using JavaScript to show/hide, you can use CSS.

<s>With radio buttons, you need to make sure that the `name` fields match (to bind them into a group) -- and unique IDs for each radio button + label.</s>

```css
label a.link2{ display: none; }
input:checked + label a.link1{ display: none; }
input:checked + label a.link2{ display: inline; }
```

```html
<h2>Group 1</h2>

<input type="checkbox" name="group1" id="url1" checked>
<label for="url1">
  <a href="https://www.google.com" class="link1">GOOGLE.COM</a>
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com" class="link2">FACEBOOK.COM</a>
</label>

<h2>Group 2</h2>

<input type="checkbox" name="group2" id="url3" checked>
<label for="url3">
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com" class="link1">STACKOVERFLOW.COM</a>
  <a href="https://www.twitter.com" class="link2">TWITTER.COM</a>
</label>
```

Comment: with your solution URLs aren't changing in place and the one which is not shows has a radio button against it. For group1 if I select radio button it should show URL1 otherwise show URL2 and there shouldn't be second radio button. This is application for each group.

Comment: Updated, brought back the checkboxes/but now it does a swap -- still no JS though :)

Comment: This totally works... I have wasted all my day for this. Many thanks. You are a star

Answer (score 0):

The css solution from doug is probably the one you want to go for. But if you want to do it with js then this is a more elegant example.

You can use `addEventListener` to attach the event. You can use the this keyword to get the current clicked element.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.urlToggler').forEach((checkbox) => {
  checkbox.addEventListener('click', function() {
      this.parentNode.querySelector('.firstUrl').style.display = this.checked ? 'inline' : 'none';
      this.parentNode.querySelector('.secondUrl').style.display = this.checked ? 'none' : 'inline';
  });
});
```

```html
<ul class="urls">
  <li>
    <label>Toggle</label>
    <input class="urlToggler" type="checkbox">
    <a class="firstUrl" style="display:none;" href="URL1">Server1 URL1</a>
    <a class="secondUrl" style="display:inline;" href="URL2">Server2 URL2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>Toggle2</label>
    <input class="urlToggler" type="checkbox">
    <a class="firstUrl" style="display:none;" href="URL1">Server1 URL3</a>
    <a class="secondUrl" style="display:inline;" href="URL2">Server2 URL4</a>
  </li>
<ul>
```

Comment: Thanks Mark this works like a charm. A little syntax error need to be fixed.